# Google Map Address from latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api i am fetching dynamically latitude and longitude from my database.
I want to show address for each position can any one tell me how can id that.

or can any anyone tell how this site is fetching address for each every position.
http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/find-address-from-latitude-and-longitude.php#.UTpYG1c9nwk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fetching the associated address from a coordinates is called [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)

The Google Maps API provides reverse geocoding in the javascript API and as a web service.

The Google Maps service is not intended for bulk use.  Your best option is to store the address in your database along with the coordinates as Reverse Geocoding is not always reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use google map api like below

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.41448,-118.93753&sensor=true

Using this api,you can get address address from key

"formatted_address" : "1271 Cliff Avenue, Fillmore, CA 93015, USA"

Whole address you can get using this api.

Hope need helpful.

Comment: api key is why not required here?? does google provide it completely free??

Comment: Got this error: Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that site is using the [Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) provided by Google.